# fixed menu and goto top button

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed top bar that when I scroll it is still showing.

Now I also have a "goto top" button at the bottom of the page which goes all the way until the top element #main.

The issue is that once I goto the top with the button, the menu results in being above the top element (don't know how to explain so check image).

[image: Before]
[image: After]

### Top elements (button leades to #main)

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="main">
  <head>
   ...
  </head>
  <body>
   <header id="header">
    ...
   </header>
   ...
  </body>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
...
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#header{ /* top bar is inside the header id */
  background: darken(#228b22, 1%);
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}  /* must be same height as the footer */

div#footer { /* sticky footer */
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -60px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 60px;
    clear:both;
}
```

top bar menu is initialized in the body. I basically need it to appear like the first image once I click on the goto top button. Manually scrolling to the top raises no issues.

Comment: Fast comments on the html used: </header should be </header> and your body-tag should surround all divs.

Answer (score 0):

The menu is 'sticky' to the top once scrolling down begins. If instead of clicking the 'goto top' button, you scroll back up to the top, does this issue still occur?

Comment: No it does not occur if one scrolls to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Because your topbar is fixed it is removed from the flow of the page. You probably gave #main or #wrap a margin-top -value to make the content appear below the topbar in response to this behavior. Now it looked good when you load the page.

**What happens now**

If you open the page at www.yourpage.com#main the main content will appear at the top of your browser. This actually ignores the margin of #main. The margin appears "above" your browser, making it look like it does.

**What to do**

So what to do...one solution would be to use javascrpt / JQuery to "code" around this. But I ll only explain the css method. Just comment if you realy, really, really want to know the javascript solution (and I ll try to make one up)

Another way is to put #wrap on a fixed position on the page. This would result into a slightly odd scrollbar and you may need to add another wrapper inside that one if you want a centered fixed-width view. Here is the CSS-code you could use on the #wrap.

```
#wrap{
position: fixed;
top: 100px;/*height you want to start you content to appear*/
left: 0; 
right: 0;   
bottom: 0px; 
overflow: auto;/*adds scrollbars when needed*/
}
#main{
margin-top: 0px; /*you are not using this top position #main anymore*/
}
```

PS: If there s a more elegant css-solution to this I d love to hear it!

Comment: I'll try to implement this solution and follow up

Comment: I have tried to implement this solution but the footer messes up Specially when I put position: fixed. Now that I have updated the answer with more code. DO you see anything that may require change in your code?

Comment: @lightbots It is really hard to see what your code does (since you are not giving us enough code). Provide a JSFiddle example to illustrate what is going wrong. Your updated question contains invalid html and I don't see how this updated question has my solution applied to it. Finally I cannot judge how the footer "messes up" if you don't supply details about what you want to do with the footer and what it does instead.